# Workaround for %ROWTYPE in Object type

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm new to PL/SQL and trying to create an object with a reference to a table row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_object AS OBJECT(
  table_row my_table%ROWTYPE
);
```

The compiler gives me the error message PLS-00329.
Ok, now I know I'm not allowed to reference a table like this. But is there a workaround?

Comment: No. You have to list each field in the object explicitly. I'm not sure what you mean by "a reference to a table row" - do you mean the object fields match the table columns; of that the object has a single field whose value somehow refers to a specific row in the table?

Comment: We have some procedures which load rows from different tables and now I want to create an object to manipulate those rows. The algorithm for the different types is always the same so I hoped to solve this by using inheritance. But I don't want to list each field because it seems to be very error prone in case of changing the table schema.

Comment: Are you sure you need schema-level object types, not just PL/SQL record types? (You can define a PL/SQL collection based on a table%rowtype, and bulk select into those.) Depends what manipulation you need to do though.

Comment: Well, I want to use some of the object orientated features like overriding functions. I didn't want to solve this with PL/SQL in the first place but I have to... so probably I have to list each field. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You have to list all of the fields in the object type declaration. You mentioned you're concerned about that being error-prone. You can semi-automate the object creation via a PL/SQL block (or procedure that you pass the table and object name into).

Say you have a table defined as;

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  ID NUMBER(38),
  col_1 DATE,
  col_2 NUMBER(3, 2),
  col_3 VARCHAR2(10),
  col_4 CLOB
);
```

You can extract the column names and data types from the data dictionary and build up your object creation statement:

```
DECLARE
  v_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  v_stmt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_object AS OBJECT(';

  FOR r IN (
    SELECT column_name,
    CAST (data_type || CASE 
      WHEN data_type IN ('VARCHAR', 'VARCHAR2', 'NVARCHAR2', 'RAW', 'CHAR')
        THEN '(' || data_length || ')'
      WHEN data_type IN ('NUMBER')
          AND (data_precision IS NOT NULL OR data_scale IS NOT NULL)
        THEN '(' || data_precision || CASE
          WHEN data_scale > 0 THEN ',' || data_scale
        END || ')'
      END AS VARCHAR2(30)) AS data_type,
      CASE WHEN column_id < MAX(column_id) OVER () THEN ',' END AS comma
    FROM user_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
    ORDER BY column_id
  )
  LOOP
    v_stmt := v_stmt || r.column_name || ' ' || r.data_type || r.comma;
  END LOOP;

  v_stmt := v_stmt || ')';

  dbms_output.put_line(v_stmt); -- just for debugging
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt;
END;
/
```

You can extract and use the nullable flag too if you want, but it may not be useful here. (This is adapted from [a `describe` replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581465/266304). There may be some data types that aren't handled properly but it covers the common ones; if you have columns with UDTs or other oddities it will need to be extended to include those properly.)

The `dbms_output` just shows the generated statement to make it easier to debug:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_object AS OBJECT(ID NUMBER(38),COL_1 DATE,COL_2 NUMBER(3,2),COL_3 VARCHAR2(10),COL_4 CLOB)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

As that statement was also executed the object was created:

```
desc my_object;

Name  Null? Type         
----- ----- ------------ 
ID          NUMBER(38)   
COL_1       DATE         
COL_2       NUMBER(3,2)  
COL_3       VARCHAR2(10) 
COL_4       CLOB
```

If you want to add functions you can use the generated create statement as a starting point, and edit it to add whatever you need before running it manually instead of using `execute immediate`.

Answer (score 0):

Convenient as it sounds, I think there is unlikely ever to be any such syntax for types, as types must present a SQL interface - you have to be able to describe the type and see its attribute list, the attributes need to be published in user_type_attrs, you have to be able to create subtypes and object-relational tables and columns from it, use it in a query and see the column projection etc.

When you create a view using `select *`, the column list is expanded on creation but does not get rebuilt if you later change the table. So even if Oracle did provide a way to do something similar with types, I suspect they would have to follow the same pattern of simply generating the list on creation and then leaving it to you to maintain, to avoid the complication of managing the dependencies and cascade invalidations, especially given the restrictions around [type evolution](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjadv.htm#ADOBJ00603) when types themselves have complex dependencies.