# SQL Query to view columns by datatype in Oracle Sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in Oracle SQLDeveloper with multiple columns. Different columns have different datatypes. I want to retrieve only those column names whose datatype is of a certain kind.

For example, I tried `Describe Employee where Type = NUMBER`

But it is giving me an error `Usage: DESCRIBE [schema.]object[@db_link]`

How do I view only those column names having datatype as Number

Comment: `describe` is a client command that runs a query in the background and formats the results. You can't modify it much. The accepted answer to the duplicate question shows the query and how to run the equivalent yourself; you just need to add a filter for the data type you're looking for. (You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581465/266304) useful if you want more formatting.)

Answer (score 1):

Query data dictionary.

This is sample table:

```
SQL> desc emp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
```

Presuming you want to see all *character*-type columns:

```
SQL> select column_name
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where table_name = 'EMP'
  4    and data_type like '%CHAR%';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
ENAME
JOB

SQL>
```

---

Check other columns in `user_tab_columns`; you might find something interesting. Description is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2103.htm#REFRN20277) (that's `all_tab_columns`; the only difference is that it contains `owner` column; documentation for `user_tab_columns` points to this document, so I thought that you'd rather see a direct link, than to make another *hop*).