# How to retrieve primary key with Perl DBI

Tags: perl, oracle12c, dbi

I try to write a script that gathers some information about tables using Perl and the DBI module.

I have already all information regarding the columns but I can't find a way to determine which column is the primary key.

I tried googling for it but somehow the only "solution" I found did not wor (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=343462)

Does anybody know how to do it? That would be very helpful

Edit:
I am querying an oracle database version 12.

Comment: This heavily depends on the database you are using. In MySQL you could just run a `SHOW CREATE <tablename>` query to get the SQL, then parse that. `DESCRIBE <tablename>` is also useful. Often the DBI:: driver has some properties on your database handle that will tell you things, too.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9855209/1331451

Comment: Thank you simbabque I think this helps me.

Comment: Check the duplicate. I think that's it. You can just run that query. My Oracle admin buddy found that answer for me.