# Oracle Pl/SQL alter table columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a `table2` with SQL query: `create table2 as select * from table1`

`Create table as select ...` doesn't retain all column properties  from `table1` in `table2`.

Is it possible to generate an SQL file to `ALTER` `table2` column properties (`DATA_LENGTH`,`DATA_PRECISION`,`DATA_SCALE`,`DEFAULT_LENGTH`,`DATA_DEFAULT`) with all column properties from `table1`?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I describe a table in Oracle without using the DESCRIBE command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855209/how-can-i-describe-a-table-in-oracle-without-using-the-describe-command)

Answer (score 1):

```
--drop table table2;

create table table1 (
 x number(10, 2) default 10,
 y varchar2(200) default 'NA'
);

create table table2 as select * from table1;
```

Let us try for data_default:

```
create table search_user_tab_columns as 
select  table_name, column_name, to_lob(DATA_DEFAULT) dd
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'TABLE1';
```

As data_default is a long data in  user_tab_columns we have to create an intermediate

```
search_user_tab_columns (dummy) :-( 
select 'ALTER TABLE "' || table_name || '" MODIFY "' || column_name || '" DEFAULT ' || Dd || ';'
  from search_user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'TABLE1';
```

Note:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','<TABLE_NAME>','<SCHEMA_NAME>') from dual;
```

This is better way of doing this if creating a table from an existing table . But sometimes you may try this for specific purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the properties.

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','<TABLE_NAME>','<SCHEMA_NAME>') from dual;
```

Comment: I need to generate a syntax from table1 similar with: ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY (column DEFAULT '0');

Comment: @Catalin - Unless you have some sort of **auditing** setup, you cannot find that information.

Comment: You will be better off getting the DDL and including the 'as select' in the DDL to create your table. I have never seen something that generates 'alter table' statements, which you can script with a bit of plsql but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I use this to generate batch: Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
,('ALTER TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME || ' MODIFY (' || COLUMN_NAME || ' DEFAULT ' || 
TRIM((CASE
      WHEN c.DEFAULT_LENGTH IS NULL
      THEN '0'
      ELSE extractvalue(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select data_default from user_tab_columns where table_name = '''
        || c.TABLE_NAME
        || ''' and column_name = '''
        || c.COLUMN_NAME
        || ''''), '//text()')
    END)
|| ')' )) AS SYNTAX
from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS C
where TABLE_NAME IN (select table from list_of_tables) AND DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

> you can see all properties

```
select column_name as "Name"
     , nullable as "Null?"
     , concat(concat(concat(data_type,'('),data_length),')') as "Type"
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```